# multiply a number with array of number without modification in original array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

multiply a number with array of number without modification in original array in JavaScript.

```js
function mul(array){
 for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
  array[i]=array[i]*3
 }
return array;
}
console.log(mul([1,2,3]));
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Add example input and output array

Answer (score 0):

use Array `map` method

```
function mul(array){
    return array.map(function(item) {
        return item * 3;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply copy it over another array

```
function mul(array)
{
    var copy = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        copy[i] = array[i] * 3;
    }
    return copy;
}
```

---

On a side note, if you don't mind about IE8- compatibility, you should probably use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var newArray = array.map(function(e){ return e * 3; });
```

Answer (score 0):

The operation you're looking for is called [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and will transform each element of an array, collecting the results as a new array.

To triple each element, you would do:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(function (n) { return n * 3; });
```